# CuRL command is not giving output as Url is not responding

Tags: curl

when url is not responding curl command does not give any output/error because of this script does not move to next line.
command:

```
/usr/bin/curl --silent --ntlm --user 'username' --url http://server.net/report --output /home/scripts
```

Is there any way to exit from url with some error output send to output file?
so script will move to next line and it will trigger a alert mail and we will take some action.

Comment: Maybe you want to set a timeout? You can check the error code to detect this. Have a look at `man curl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl` has a `--max-time <seconds>` option which you can use to avoid the entire operation taking too long.